# Socket.IO Can't Access Array Outside

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, websocket, socket.io

I listen every events and made a loop. The problem is when I open page, all of them's class is "white-text". But when data comes from show_inventory the class should be "magenta-text".

Sorry for my little English.

```
var events = {
    log_stats:                         'magenta',
    show_inventory:                    'magenta',
    arrived_at_cluster:                'white',
    arrived_at_fort:                   'white',
    softban_log:                       'magenta',
    softban_fix_done:                  'white',
    used_lucky_egg:                    'white'
}   

socket_io = io.connect('127.0.0.1:4000');
for (var k in events){      
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        socket_io.on(k+':user', function (data) {
            mapView.log({
                message: "<p class='" + events[k] + "-text" + "'>" + data['data']['msg'] + "</p>",
                color: events[k] + "-text"
            });

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: mapView.log() isn't a synchronous function, by the time it compiles and executes, the variable k has been overwritten to the last iteration of the array, the colour white, you can verify this by changing the value of the last key in your array to magenta; this will make all text magenta. To fix this you should create a handler function or a simple setTimeout might do the job '''setTimeout(function(j){/** your map log thing */}, 100, k);''' I'm writing this on mobile at 1:38 AM, so don't take this as 100%, wait for a direct answer or continue to search for your problem with different key words.

Comment: This is a common issue with async code such as event handlers inside a `for` loop.  The variable `k` will not be what you want it to be some time later when the `.on()` event actually fires.  You can use a closure, switch to `let` to you get a unique block scope variable, etc...  There are hundreds of duplicate questions that discuss this same issue.

Comment: I'm sure there is but I don't know how to search.. But it is about async code.. Let me make a search

Comment: @Robinlemon I'm still trying to fix it but I'm not sure I understand the things

Comment: I'll provide a code demo tomorrow, 2:30 right now. If you ever get frustrated, just take a few minutes to think, or if it's late just sleep, it will help you on the long run.

Comment: yes, it is too late, but I have to figure it out. It's 4:26 a.m. I have to sleep, too. before I should make a little search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. @jfriend00 mentioned about `let`. I searched a little and understand the usage. You can find the code belove. Added line: `let color = events[k];`

Thanks a lot.

```
for (var k in events){      
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        let color = events[k];
        socket_io.on(k+':oralunal', function (data) {
                kayit({
                    message: "<p class='" + color + "-text" + "'>" + data['data']['msg'] + "</p>",
                    color: color + "-text"
                });
                console.log(renk);
        });
    }
}
```